# how to convert a song as time varying wave in python and add noise to it and play it again?

Tags: python, audio, signals

I am trying to extract a feature from a song in python and plot it as a signal, then add random noise to it and play it back as a noisy signal. How can I do this?

I can do the following to extract the input_data from the song. What's the best way to proceed from here?

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
input_data = read("Sample.wav")
```

Comment: What does input_data look like? Is it PCM? Whatever the range is, if it is the signal itself, I think you should be able to replace some random elements with random numbers in the same range, or add random numbers of a certain range to the signal. Often we are dealing with floats from -1 to 1, so either generate some randoms in that range and swap them in or add them in. I don't know how much though--will have to experiment and listen.

Comment: Hi @PhilFreihofner I can work on adding the noise. But what I am confused about the input_data. I pretty much want the signal (time in x-axis, not sure about the y-axis). I want to add a noise and then try to de-noise using a algorithm and play the song again. Just tell me how to play it again?

Comment: If you don't know specifics of your y-axis, or what PCM is, I'm guessing you don't know very much at all about audio formatting. I thought from the question you might be further along. I'm not experienced with the specifics of python audio support, am more a Java guy. If the read() command you are doing is just a raw read of the .wav file, you will be creating needless trouble for yourself, as you will have to deal with headers and decoding and recoding. Surely Python has audio file reading support (or libraries or code written by others) that reads .wav files.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import Audio

song, sr = librosa.load('Song.mp3')

mu = 0;
sigma = 0.1 #you'll want to adjust sigma to adjust the noise level
noise = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,len(song))

distorted_song = song + noise
Audio(distorted_song, rate = sr)
```